# CSS style not work in safari browser in mac

Tags: css, safari

I am trying to show only two lines inside `div` and dots if the text exceeds 2 lines. In other browsers in windows and ubuntu it's working perfectly, but in safari browser in mac, all divs are not showing properly.

Here is my code:

```css
body {
   margin: 20px;
}

.text {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /* number of lines to show */
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam consectetur venenatis blandit. Praesent vehicula, libero non pretium vulputate, lacus arcu facilisis lectus, sed feugiat tellus nulla eu dolor. Nulla porta bibendum lectus quis euismod. Aliquam volutpat ultricies porttitor. Cras risus nisi, accumsan vel cursus ut, sollicitudin vitae dolor. Fusce scelerisque eleifend lectus in bibendum. Suspendisse lacinia egestas felis a volutpat.
</div>
```

Comment: Which Safari are you using? It's working on my Mac.

Comment: @technophyle I use for testin safari 10.1.  MacOS Sierra. in safari all text not showing

Comment: It's working fine on my mac with safari Version 13.0.4 as well.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-line-clamp